# Need help with XNA's content pipeline (2Qs)

Tags: c#, xna

I ask *here* about XNA and not on it's official forums because people from my country are not allowed to sign in to the new XNA website.

Well, these are my questions:

1. I want to use some 2D images I create in Paint Shop Pro/Photo Shop/Paint, but for some reason I need to use web safe pallet and such settings for it to be displayed currently (I use transparency).
   could any1 please explain to me how can I use transparency & other settings (while creating & saving the image) so that the XNA (4.0) could display it correctly?
   By the way, it might be that I just need some 1 to explain to me how to set the "GraphicsDevice"-s settings to work with transparency layer/channel.
2. I really do try to do things as I am supposed to (by Microsoft's view) & thus I use the content pipeline for *ALL* of my content loading (including classes initiation data files).
   I use *.txt* files for storing my class initiation data & I edit them with simple good old notepad (++ :P).
   Now, the problem is that all I managed to do is loading the *.txt* file as a really long string instead of creating a new instance of my GameDataFile class.
   because of that I was forced to do it in 2 steps:

Step 1:

```
string tempStrData = content.load<string>("data/filename").Replace("\r", "");
```

`/* Loads a string from a file (the string is the whole file!) */`

Step 2:

```
GameDataFile gameDataFile = new GameDataFile(tempStrData.Split('\n'));
/* Sends the string to my GameDataFile class constructor which knows how to handle that string and break it to it's data elements (ints, strings vectors, etc...) */
```

I want to upgrade it to be of the following form:

```
GameDataFile gameDataFile = content.load<GameDataFile>("data/fileName");
```

I think I should do this using a custom Content pipeline Processor, any opinions if I'm right & how should I achieve that?

P.S please don't make me to use public members as I always set that to private and I hate and strictly forbid myself from using the C#-ONLY-get-&-set methods.

Thanks In Advance, Tal A.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, set the blendstate to AlphaBlend when you begin your SpriteBatch:

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend, null, null, null);
```

I save my images as PNGs in PhotoShop which allows transparency.

Edit: Unless you're referring to 3D textures. If so I'll have to revise my answer

Edit: As for question 2, [this example](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/education/catalog/sample/custom_model_importer) on App Hub shows how to do it.

Comment: I tried using ur line of code instead of my plain "spritebatch.Begin()" with a .png file set to channel transparency & 24 Bit of colors with no positive effect. I also tried this line of code on a .png with layer transparency, the difference with that with channel it had a black square background and the layer transparency had a white background.

Comment: The sample works, but its forcing me to add: 1. A parameterless constructor, 2. (C#-brand-of-set&get methods || make my members public). with problem no. 1 I can survive, but the demand of **PUBLIC** **MEMBERS** is outrageous! it is just unheard of! is there no work around these demands?! thanks in advance.

Comment: @John I don't know what the problem is then, but I suspect it might be the type of PNG you're creating. When I draw in Photoshop it's 32-bit, with 8-bit per channel. As for the App Hub sample it's honestly not something I've looked into so I can't help off the top of my head. I'm not aware of work arounds for that.